# Remove() method in ObservableCollection and List leads performance issue with large amount of data

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection

I have used the observable collection with 500k records. In certain case, I want to remove those records using Foreach loop. it takes more than 1 minute to remove the 500k records. same list collection also takes 1 minute. Is there any solution to improve the performance of observable collection?

```
ObservableCollection<string> collection;

collection = new ObservableCollection<string>();
for(int i=0; i< 500000; i++)
{
    collection.Add("Item" + i);
}

private void RemoveBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    var items = collection.ToList();
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        collection.Remove(item);
    }
}
```

[image: Time taken image]

Comment: Your code does not remove 5 items of the observable collection, but all of them. This can also be done easily with `collection.Clear()`

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like lac / lakh here. The rest of the world doesn't use or understand them.

Comment: In general, you shouldn't use observable collections of this size.
If you provide additional information why you needed an observable collection of such a huge size, we may be able to indicate a more optimal solution to your problem as a whole.
The observable collection is bound in the view and each deletion / addition in it is also a change in the view.
It is not yet clear in which thread you are modifying the collection.
If it is in the UI thread, then it further slows down the execution.
And if not on the UI thread, how do you keep your collection in sync with the View?

Comment: Not only ObsevableCollection, List collection also get 1 minute for removing the 500,000 records. I need to check the condition for removing items and if condition is true, I will remove those items only. So, In my case, I wont use the collection.clear().

Answer (score 3):

Your code appears to be shallow cloning the collection to a list, then removing every item in series. Is that intentional? If you're trying to clear the entire list, `collection.Clear()` would be more performant.

If you already know the index of the object you're trying to remove, it may be quicker to use `collection.RemoveAt(i)` rather than `collection.Remove(e)`, which is effectively doing an `IndexOf` and then `RemoveAt` internally. See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,f63ea2601f5edbbb.

Depending on your object, the equals comparison may also cause some slow down (used by `IndexOf`).